# Is there a way to sort multiple values, and keep only the largest of each?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have some code producing an output of a location type and a maximum quantity.

I would like to keep only the largest of each combination of these values. But I'm unsure of the best approach that will allow for n locations.

Data is currently generated and stored as a list of strings, stored with spaces between locations.

```
var locationOutputDistinct = new List<string>
{
"PERSON:2 ",
"PERSON:1 SCOOTER:1 ",
"PERSON:1 BIKE:1 ",
"PERSON:2 BIKE:1 ",
"PERSON:1 BIKE:1 SCOOTER:1 ",
"PERSON:3 ",
"PERSON:3 BIKE:1 ",
"PERSON:4 ",
"PERSON:4 BIKE:1 ",
"PERSON:2 SCOOTER:1 ",
"PERSON:5 ",
"PERSON:3 SCOOTER:1 ",
"PERSON:6 "
};
```

Ideal output would look something like:

```
PERSON:1 BIKE:1 SCOOTER:1 
PERSON:4 BIKE:1 
PERSON:3 SCOOTER:1 
PERSON:6
```

Indicating that you can have 6 people, or 3 people and a scooter, or 4 people and a bike, or 1 person, 1 bike, and 1 scooter. Each the largest combination of their respective types.

What is the best approach to this?

Here are some other data sets and expected results. https://justpaste.it/6cce5

Here is a visual example, and explanation of what I'm trying to produce. https://justpaste.it/4vqu2

Comment: Is that the actual output you'd want? If it is then I'm not following how you'd expect to obtain that specific information from the given set.

Comment: You want to sort by `FRNT` number and for each distinct `FRNT`, get the one with most properties/attributes? Also, what happened with all the odd numbers?

Comment: @mariocatch Yes, I'm trying to get the "largest" set from each group. Where FRNT:8 is greater than FRNT:7,6,5, etc. Then, FRNT:6 ROOF:1 is greater than FRNT:5,4,3 ROOF:1.

Comment: @magnetron This example just had an even number of available "spots". Odd numbers do occur. My concern with just geting distinct FRNT, is there are cases where there might not be a FRNT, it could just be REAR:1 ROOF:2.

Comment: Ok, and a group is defined by the "FRONT: {N}" format? So a FRNT:8 would beat any combination of any FRNT's that are lower than 8? even if they have roofs and rears/etc?

Comment: What if you have `FRNT:5 ROOF:2`, do you expect the output to be `FRNT:6 ROOF:1` or `FRNT:5 ROOF:2`, since one the FRNT is greater, but the other it is the ROOF that is greater?

Comment: A group probably is better defined as an occurrence of  "FRONT: {N} REAR: {N} ROOF: {N}" or  "FRONT: {N} ROOF: {N}"

Comment: My head hurts thinking about that :x

Comment: @magnetron I'm only trying to get the largest occurrence of each number in a group. So `FRNT:5 ROOF:2` is greater than `FRNT:5 ROOF:1` and `FRNT:4 REAR:1 ROOF:2` is greater than  `FRNT:4 REAR:1 ROOF:1`

Comment: @magnetron I've clarified the question with better names. It might be easier to imagine it as a case of "How many people, and bikes, and scooters, can I fit on a bus?"

Comment: @mariocatch I've clarified the question with better names. It might be easier to imagine it as a case of "How many people, and bikes, and scooters, can I fit on a bus?"

Comment: The best approach is not putting everything into one string for starters.

Comment: @Zer0 No problem storing them any other way, what would your suggestion be?

Comment: Which value has the largest intrinsic weight, or are they all equal? So say does a person = a scooter? or does 3 people = 1 scooter? I know it's an odd question, but I'm thinking outside of the box for a solution to the problem

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth These values are based upon a graphical drawing the user creates, so there are cases where Person = Scooter, and cases where 3 people = scooter.

Comment: Will there ever be an option to have a scooter but no people or will there always be people?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth There is always an option of no scooter, or the addition of any number of other things. ie: there could be 25 different kinds of scooter.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Yes, but here are some other data sets to test against. [https://justpaste.it/6cce5](https://justpaste.it/6cce5)

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Updated code with a visual explanation and more detailed write up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on 2 classes

```
public class Res{
    public string Key;
    public int Val;
}
public class Reduced
{
    public string Key;
    public IEnumerable<Res>[] invalid;
}
```

You can use this code to aggregate the results.

```
    var loc =
   locationOutputDistinct
   .Select(x => x.Trim().Split(' ').ToArray()
   .Select(
       y => {
           var kv = y.Split(':');
           return new Res()
           {
               Key = kv[0],
               Val = int.Parse
                (kv[1])
           };
       }).ToArray()).ToArray()

    .GroupBy(x =>
       String.Join(",",
       x.Select(y => y.Key))
       );
```

Then you have to apply your reduction rule

```
    var reduced = 
    loc.Select(x => new Reduced() {
    Key = x.Key,                 
            invalid =
                x.Where(y => loc.Any(ext => ext.Any(xsup =>
                   y.All(z => xsup.Any(xsupcell => xsupcell.Key == z.Key)) &&
                   y.All(z =>
                   z.Val <= xsup
                         .Where(xsupcell =>
                   xsupcell.Key == z.Key)
                         .First().Val) &&
                         ((xsup.Length > y.Length) ||
                   y.Any(z =>
                   z.Val < xsup
                         .Where(xsupcell =>
                   xsupcell.Key == z.Key)
                         .First().Val))

                    ))).ToArray()
                            });

    var remain = loc.Select(x => x.Where(y =>
    !reduced.Where(r => r.Key == x.Key).SelectMany(r2 => r2.invalid).Any(r3 => r3.All(r4 =>
    y.Any(y2 => y2.Key == r4.Key && y2.Val == r4.Val)))));
```

From your last example, I see that you want to reduce also less extended combinations `y` with more extended ones (`xsup.Length > y.Length`), so I've included this last feature in the code above.

At this point you need to unwrap and print the results.

```
    foreach (var x in remain)
        Console.WriteLine
        (//x.Key+": " +
          String.Join("\n",
          x.Select(y =>
          String.Join(" ",
          y.Select(z => z.Key + ":" + z.Val)
              ))));
```

From the original sequence in your question you will get

```
PERSON:6
PERSON:3 SCOOTER:1
PERSON:4 BIKE:1
PERSON:1 BIKE:1 SCOOTER:1
```

and from

```
"AM:4 SC:1 ",
"AM:4 WC:1 ",
"AM:4 WC:1 SC:1 ",
"AM:4 WC:2 ",
"AM:4 WC:2 SC:1 ",
"AM:5 ",
"AM:5 WC:1 ",
"AM:6 ",
"AM:6 WC:1 ",
"AM:7 ",
"AM:8 "
```

you will get

```
AM:6 WC:1
AM:4 WC:2 SC:1
AM:8
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m7ytMQ).

Comment: Using the values commented below, this solution produces the result "AM:8 SC:2" and "AM:10", where "AM:8 SC:2" is not in the original options.

AM:6 SC:1, 
AM:6 SC:2, 
AM:7, 
AM:7 SC:1, 
AM:8, 
AM:8 SC:1, 
AM:9, 
AM:10

Comment: The string is a max combination as determined one step earlier, so "AM:8 SC:1" and "AM:6 SC:2" are both valid combinations but "AM:7 SC:1" is less than "AM:8 SC:1"

Comment: Yes that is correct, "AM:10" "AM:8 SC:1" and "AM:6 SC:2" are the correct output.

Comment: This is very close to my end goal, I'm running into an issue however where its overwriting some results. I will attempt to diagnose.

Comment: This appears to work exactly as I wanted. I will test with some difficult scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The following works :

```
            var locationOutputDistinct = new List<string>
            {
                "FRNT:2 REAR:1 ",
                "FRNT:2 ROOF:1 ",
                "FRNT:2 ROOF:1 REAR:1 ",
                "FRNT:3 ",
                "FRNT:3 REAR:1 ",
                "FRNT:4 ",
                "FRNT:4 REAR:1 ",
                "FRNT:3 ROOF:1 ",
                "FRNT:5 ",
                "FRNT:4 ROOF:1 ",
                "FRNT:6 ",
                "FRNT:5 ROOF:1 ",
                "FRNT:7 ",
                "FRNT:6 ROOF:1 ",
                "FRNT:8 "
            };
            var parsedData = locationOutputDistinct
                .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(y.Substring(0, y.IndexOf(":")), int.Parse(y.Substring(y.IndexOf(":") + 1)))).OrderBy(z => z.Key).ToList())
                    .ToList();

            var groups = parsedData
                .GroupBy(x => string.Join("^", x.Select(y => y.Key)))
                .ToList();

            var results = groups.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y).GroupBy(z => z.Key).Select(z => new { Key = z.Key, Value = z.Max(a => a.Value)}).ToList()).ToList();
            List<string> strings = results.Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.Key + ":" + y.Value.ToString()))).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution appears to return a P:8 S:2 using the below commented data set, a set of values that doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: "P:2 B:1 ",
"P:2 L:1 ",
"P:2 W:1 ",
"P:2 W:2 ",
"P:2 S:1 ",
"P:2 S:1 L:1 ",
"P:2 S:1 W:1 ",
"P:2 S:1 W:2 ",
"P:2 S:2 ",
"P:2 S:2 L:1 ",
"P:3 ",
"P:3 L:1 ",
"P:3 W:1 ",
"P:3 W:2 ",
"P:3 S:1 ",
"P:3 S:1 L:1 ",
"P:3 S:1 W:1 ",
"P:4 ",
"P:4 L:1 ",
"P:4 W:1 ",
"P:3 S:2 ",
"P:4 S:1 ",
"P:4 S:1 W:1 ",
"P:5 ",
"P:5 W:1 ",

Comment: "P:3 B:1 ",
"P:3 S:1 W:2 ",
"P:4 W:2 ",
"P:4 S:2 ",
"P:5 S:1 ",
"P:5 S:1 W:1 ",
"P:6 ",
"P:6 W:1 ",
"P:4 S:1 L:1 ",
"P:5 L:1 ",
"P:5 W:2 ",
"P:6 S:1 ",
"P:7 ",
"P:7 W:1 ",
"P:6 L:1 ",
"P:8 ",
"P:5 S:2 ",
"P:7 S:1 ",
"P:9 ",
"P:4 B:1 ",
"P:4 S:1 W:2 ",
"P:6 S:1 W:1 ",
"P:6 W:2 ",
"P:8 W:1 ",
"P:6 S:2 ",
"P:8 S:1 ",
"P:10 "

Comment: I have no idea with my code posted how you are getting your results.  Add one line to make each result a string.  The code give following with original data : FRNT:4 REAR:1;FRNT:6 ROOF:1;FRNT:2 REAR:1 ROOF:1;FRNT:8 and following with updated inputs : PERSON:6;PERSON:3 SCOOTER:1;BIKE:1 PERSON:4;BIKE:1 PERSON:1 SCOOTER:1

Comment: To clarify, the updated set of values I commented gives some weird results.

Comment: Look at my last response.  It gives correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The below LINQ queries will give you the expected result. First we are grouping by the names without the numbers since that will always be the same. Then we iterate over the groupings and calculate the max sum that we need to match on, and lastly we get the record from our group with the matching sum.

```
var groupedLocation = locationOutputDistinct.GroupBy(x => new string(x.Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()))
                                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Length)
                                            .ToList();

foreach(var group in groupedLocation)
{
    var maxSum = group.Max(x => x.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))
                      .Select(z => char.GetNumericValue(z)).Sum());
    var matchingRecord = group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Select(z => char.GetNumericValue(z)).Sum() == maxSum);

    Console.WriteLine(matchingRecord);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Although this seems to cease functioning correctly with larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this solution knowing that my output does not match your sample output. That is because I disagree with your output.

for example, one output sample you have provides the following:

```
OUTPUT:
AM:10 BK:1 
AM:8 BK:1 BWC:1 
AM:8 BK:1 WC:1 
AM:7 BK:1 SC:1
AM:6 BK:1 BWC:2 
AM:6 BK:1 BWC:1 WC:1 
AM:6 BK:1 WC:2 
AM:5 BK:1 BWC:1 SC:1
AM:5 BK:1 WC:1 SC:1
AM:4 BK:1 BWC:2 WC:1 
AM:4 BK:1 WC:3 
AM:4 BK:1 SC:2
AM:2 BK:1 WC:1 SC:2
```

But `AM:4 BK:1 WC:3` is less than `AM:8 BK:1 WC:1` so I don't believe both of those should be a result and there are multiple examples of this. That being said, here is my solution that gets the absolute max for each possible combination of input.

The execution:

```
        // Get all the `keys` in the location output
        var keys = GetKeys(locationOutputDistinct);
        // Get the possible combinations of keys
        var combinations = GetCombination(keys);

        var maxCombos = new List<string>();

        foreach (var combo in combinations)
        {
            var maxOfCombo = GetMaxOfCombo(locationOutputDistinct, combo);
            if (maxOfCombo.Any())
            {
                maxCombos.AddRange(maxOfCombo);
            }
        }

        maxCombos = maxCombos.Distinct().ToList();
        maxCombos.Sort();
        foreach (var maxCombo in maxCombos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(maxCombo);
        }
```

And the supporting methods:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Get the keys from the input and return it in a `;` delimited string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vals">Input list</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetKeys(List<string> vals)
    {
        var keys = new List<string>();
        foreach (var grouping in vals)
        {
            var parameters = grouping.Split(' ');
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var paramVals = parameter.Split(':');
                var label = paramVals[0].Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label) && !keys.Contains(label))
                {
                    keys.Add(label);
                }
            }
        }

        return keys;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Take all the keys and return all possible combinations of them
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">List of keys</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetCombination(List<string> list)
    {
        var combos = new List<string>();
        var comb = "";
        double count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            var sep = "";
            string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');
            for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[j] == '1')
                {
                    comb += sep + list[j];
                    sep = ";";
                }
            }

            combos.Add(comb);
            comb = "";
        }

        return combos;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the combinations that have the largest values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">String list of input</param>
    /// <param name="combo">`;` delimited keys you're checking</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetMaxOfCombo(List<string> source, string combo)
    {
        var comboKeys = combo.Split(';');
        var matchingCombos = source.Where(s => comboKeys.All(a => s.IndexOf(a) != -1) && s.Trim().Split(' ').Length == comboKeys.Count());

        // Return empty set if there were none
        if (!matchingCombos.Any())
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

        var comboValues = matchingCombos.Select(mc => new
        {
            // Get the value sum of the individual keys
            value = mc.Split(' ').Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Trim())).Sum(s => int.Parse(string.Concat(s.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))))),
            label = mc
        });
        // Get the max value
        var max = comboValues.Max(m => m.value);
        // Get all that have the same max
        var maxCombos = comboValues.Where(f => f.value == max);

        if (!maxCombos.Any())
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        return maxCombos.Select(s => s.label).ToList();
    }
```

Here's a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwpkMO

Comment: Thanks, however AM:4 BK:1 WC:3 is not less than AM:8 BK:1 WC:1, as in this example, its the only case where the "vehicle" could accept 3-wheelchairs.

Comment: @Ethan, Since there's no consistency, there's no way to get the results you're looking for. Either each has a specific weight, or they're all equal. Their weights can't change depending on the situation unless there are rules to them.

Comment: Ultimately I'm failing to explain this as clearly and concisely as I can. You're right, I had intended there would be no weight applied to any solution, but I'm seeing that one item is going to have to be the value that everything else is compared against. ie: `P:9 > P:8 > P:7` & `P:9 S:2 > P:8 S:2`